# How to get key value from data

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell, and want to parse JSON for user.

Have this kind of сode:

```
import Data.Aeson as Q
import Data.Text
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import Network.HTTP.Conduit (simpleHttp)
import GHC.Generics

data DataPoint = DataPoint { id :: Int
                           , description :: String
                           , icon :: String
                           } deriving (Show, Generic)

data Temperatures = Temperatures { weather :: [DataPoint]
                                 } deriving (Show, Generic)

instance FromJSON Temperatures
instance ToJSON Temperatures
instance FromJSON DataPoint
instance ToJSON DataPoint`

jsonURL :: String -> String
jsonURL q = "url here hidden"

getJSON :: String -> IO B.ByteString
getJSON town = simpleHttp (jsonURL town)

main :: IO ()
main = do
 putStrLn "Hello! Please insert your town >>> \n "
 town <- getLine
 putStrLn ("Your town is: " ++ town ++ "\n")
 d <- (eitherDecode <$> (getJSON town)) :: IO (Either String Temperatures)
 case d of
  Left e -> putStrLn "Error occured. Try again please"
  Right stuff -> putStrLn (fmap weather) $ stuff
```

Want to show id and description but map not the right way, is int?
And is okey to store data like this or I should

Comment: Could you clarify your question? I barely understand your problem. I don't get what are you going to print – `(fmap weather)` is definitely not the thing

Comment: I also don't understand the question, but the last line should probably be `Right stuff -> putStrLn $ weather stuff`

Answer (score 1):

> Want to show id and description but map not the right way, is int?

**Yes**, it is not the right way.

Actually, you can get the list of `DataPoint` from `Temperatures` using `weather` as:

```
weather stuff
```

and print the `id` and `description` from list of `DataPoint` using `mapM_` as:

```
import Control.Monad (mapM_)
import Prelude hiding (id)

...
Right stuff -> mapM_ (\d->putStrLn (show (id d) ++ " " ++ (description d))) 
                     (weather stuff)
...
```

Notes that, it need to hide `id` function from `Prelude`. Otherwise `Ambiguous occurrence` error will occur.